# How to pass multiple params into a delegate in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS code, which uses jQuery:

```
var anArray=[];
var passIntoFun =100; // calculated value;

function ArrayIteratorFun(index, element, thirdParam){
   // function code.
}
```

I want to call ArrayIteratorFun using .each construct, like:

```
$(anArray).each(ArrayIteratorFun(passIntoFun));
```

I could only call it like, by wrapping into a function:

```
$(anArray).each(function(i,e){ArrayIteratorFun(i,e,passIntoFun);});
```

is there any better way to write the code above?

Comment: You have access to the variable in your callback, why do you want to pass it as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming your example is oversimplified and your function does not have access to the variable you wish to pass in as an argument (as one comment alludes to)...**

The problem you have is that of *pre-filling* certain arguments (`thirdParam` in your case) of your `ArrayIteratorFun`.  Sometimes you'll see this kind of technique called partial application or currying.

You happen to want to apply the third argument (leaving the preceding ones unfilled), which removes the possibility of using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).  Bind is useful, but I often use the more flexible [`partial`](http://underscorejs.org/#partial) function from [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).

With `partial` you can apply arbitrary arguments, by using _ in place of arguments that you want to apply/fill later:

```
$(anArray).each(_.partial(ArrayIteratorFun, _, _, passIntoFun));
```

The above ignores the first 2 arguments of `ArrayIteratorFun` (using underscores) and applies the value of `passIntoFun` to the third argument.

**EDIT:** I'm not aware of any way that jQuery provides of doing the same thing as `_.partial`.  However if you are restricted to not using underscore (or a similar framework) then I recommend you check out [the implementation](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) of `partial` in underscore and [this great article](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/) on the subject of partial application in javascript.  These both provide ways of implementing using only plain javascript.

Comment: He tagged the question as jQuery, not underscore. I do not think he will use this solution.

Comment: I agree, however the problem is one of functional programming - and by introducing a utility like underscore that provides far more in this area than jQuery, I was hoping it might help in the future at least.  I will edit the answer with an alternative.